# How to add a Effect to a DrawingGroup in WPF in Net 4

Tags: wpf, bitmapeffect

As BitmapEffects are obsolete, how can I add a Effect to a DrawingGroup in WPF4?

Comment: That depends on how you want to display the DrawingGroup. You may set the Effect property of an Image control that shows your DrawingGroup in a DrawingImage.

Comment: No, that does not work. I only wanted a Effect on a Part of the Drawing. The DrawingGroup has the Property "BitmapEffects", but this has no Effect.
Problem is, I'd like to use it in https://github.com/dotnetprojects/SVGImage to increase svg support (and svg supports it on every part of the drawing)